# How to sync a controlled component with the URL query params, in a React Router app?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-router, react-router-dom

With the help of Create React App, I made a [web app](https://github.com/ggiuffre/timelines) that displays a timeline of events. Each event is associated with one or more topics, and users can filter the timeline by topic with the help of a small form at the top of the page. (For example: a user loads the page and sees a timeline of events; the user interacts with the form to search for a specific topic; the user submits the topic through the form; the timeline gets updated accordingly.)

**Note**: Sorry in advance if I will be using ES6 classes instead of just functions. I will reconsider my writing style in the coming weeks :)

## Problem setting

At the core of my web app is an `App` component, which renders two sub-components:

- `FilterForm`, a form with a search bar and a submit button;
- `Timeline`, a list of items related to the last topic that was submitted through `FilterForm`.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      topic: ''
    };
    this.updateTopic = this.updateTopic.bind(this);
    this.updateTimeline = this.updateTimeline.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateTimeline();
  }

  updateTopic(event) {
    this.setState({topic: event.target.value});
  }

  updateTimeline(event) {
    // avoid refreshing the page:
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    // update the state of the timeline:
    fetch('/api?topic=' + this.state.topic)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(items => this.setState({items: items}));
  }

  render() {
    return <React.Fragment>
      <FilterForm
        topic={this.state.topic}
        updateTopic={this.updateTopic}
        updateTimeline={this.updateTimeline}
      />
      <Timeline items={this.state.items} />
    </React.Fragment>;
  }
}
```

`FilterForm` is a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) that calls the `updateTopic` method of `App`:

```js
class FilterForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.updateTopic = this.props.updateTopic;
    this.updateTimeline = this.props.updateTimeline;
    fetch('/api/tags')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(tags => tags.map(tag => <option value={tag} key={tag} />))
      .then(options => this.options = options);
  }

  render() {
    return <form onSubmit={this.updateTimeline}>
      <label id="topic">Topic: <input
          type="text"
          value={this.props.topic}
          onChange={this.updateTopic}
          list="topics"
        />
      </label>
      <datalist id="topics">
        {this.options}
      </datalist>

      <label>
        <input type="submit" value="Update" />
      </label>
    </form>;
  }
}
```

`Timeline` is really just a list of items:

```js
class Timeline extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <ul className="Timeline">
      {this.props.items
        .map((item, idx) =>
          <TimelineItem
            key={item.name}
            name={item.name}
            topics={item.topics}
          />
        )
      }
    </ul>;
  }
}
```

And finally a `TimelineItem` is a list item that contains a sub-list with all the topics to which this item is related:

```js
class TimelineItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <li className="TimelineItem">
      {this.props.name}
      <ul className="tagsList">
        {this.props.topics.map(topic =>
          <li key={topic}>{topic}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </li>;
  }
}
```

## Problem

Given this setup, I decided that each topic choice should be associated with a unique URL like `/?topic=example`: opening this URL in a browser should show a timeline about the topic `example`, and vice-versa submitting a topic through the HTML form would update the URL accordingly. In order to add this features, I thought I'd use [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/).

I am new to React Router, so after some reading I thought I'd do the following:

- wrap my `App` component inside a `BrowserRouter` element
- `export default withRouter(App)`, instead of just `export default App`
- in the `App` constructor, get the `topic` query parameter from the URL (`new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search).get('topic')`) and use it to initialize `this.state`.

This way, manually setting the URL works as expected: the timeline shown depends on the URL, and the HTML form contains the topic set in the URL. However, the reverse doesn't hold: when submitting the HTML form, *the URL doesn't update*.

### Additional problem

Moreover, I also wanted to have each item show a sub-list of links instead of just topics: clicking on a topic inside an item would update the timeline to match the topic that was clicked. Now, substituting `{topic}` with `<Link to={'/?topic=' + topic}>{topic}</Link>` inside `TimelineItem` updates the URL, *but doesn't update the timeline itself*.

## Questions

I'd like some general input on my solution to the two problems I have described, and to do this you could answer the following specific questions:

- Is my web app ready to get these two new features, or should it be radically changed?
- Is it OK to not have any `action` attribute inside my HTML form and just rely on JavaScript, like I am doing now?
- How can I have the URL reflect what was submitted through the form? (problem 1)
- What's missing to have my React Router `Link`s actually refresh the page? (problem 2)

Thank you in advance, and please let me know if you need even more information.

P.S. please note that `/api/tags`, `/api?topic=example` and `/?topic=example` are three different endpoints: the first two talk to the back-end, while the third one is the front-end.

Comment: Sorry, this is more like a code review. But about syncing the component state with the Router, I encountered a similar problem and created a package for it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-route-as-state